# Can not find Server Explorer on visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am looking for Server Explorer in my visual studio 2017 in order to connect a database but I cannot find it. I saw some solution here on this site and I tried to perform them but I still can not find it. Can someone help me please.

[image]

Comment: Ctrl-Q, server... and it should be on the list

Comment: Hi, i tried that but i cannot still find the server explorer

Answer (score 1):

Open up Visual Studio Command Prompt

> **Start** -> **Microsoft Visual Studio 2005** -> **Visual Studio Tools** -> **Visual Studio 2005 Command Prompt**

Type in the command prompt:

```
devenv /resetsettings
```

or

```
devenv /setup
```

**Reference:**

https://forums.asp.net/t/1227004.aspx?Server+Explorer+not+showing+up+on+Visual+Studio